# Can you copy/import a node from one XML document to another?

Tags: xml, perl

I have two XML documens with the following format:

First document:

```
<person> 
  <name>David</name> 
</person>
```

Second document:

```
<person> 
  <name>David</name> 
  <hobby>Skating</hobby> 
</person>
```

Is it possible to copy that second node `<hobby>Skating</hobby>` into the first XML, if it doesnt already exist? I am using XML::SemanticDiff to find the XPath of the differences and LibXML to append text to changes made in that node:

```
for my $node ($root->findnodes($path_change)) { 
  $root->removeChildNodes(); 
  $node->appendText("This is a test"); 
}
```

Comment: @jdwilemo Can you show me how? Not sure how to check whether that node exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my ($dst_person) = $dst_root->findnodes('//person');
my ($dst_hobby) = $dst_person->findnodes('hobby');
if (!$dst_hobby) {
   my ($src_hobby) = $src_root->findnodes('//person/hobby');
   $dst_person->appendChild( $src_hobby->clone(1) );
}
```

Comment: @user1322582, There was a double-bug in my code. (`if (() == ...)` should have been `if (!( () = ... ))`.) Fixed by using something more readable.

Comment: What if the xml schema structure is unknown? and I want to clone a node using the attribute name for example "some_string" in this format? <name id="some_string"> Is there a way to traverse an XMl document looking for "some_string"?

Comment: @user1322582, Yes, XPaths can look for attributes.